# append select box using script in angular.js version 1

Tags: angularjs

**i want to add values for select box through script.**
**// html code**

```
<html>
 <body>
 <p>
    <select ng-model="selectedValue" ng-option="c1.name in c1 in c in personInfo.city"></select>
    </p>
 </body>
 >/html>
```

**// script**

```
$scope.personInfo = {};

            $scope.personInfo.city = [
            {name:"Select City Name", value:""},
            {name:"Pune", value:"P"},
            {name:"Mumbai", value:"M"},
            {name:"Delhi", value:"D"},
            {name:"Kerla", value:"K"},
            ];
```

Comment: Please explain your question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your option should be `ng-options="item as item.name for item in personInfo.city"`

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope, $timeout) {
$scope.personInfo = {};

            $scope.personInfo.city = [
            {name:"Select City Name", value:""},
            {name:"Pune", value:"P"},
            {name:"Mumbai", value:"M"},
            {name:"Delhi", value:"D"},
            {name:"Kerla", value:"K"},
            ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<select ng-options="item as item.name for item in personInfo.city" ng-model="selected"></select>
</div>
```